# create flexible links in d3 tree paths

Tags: d3.js

I'm new to D3 js. I would like to draw a tree structure using d3. However, I want the paths between my nodes to be flexible unlike the usual diagonal and projection methods. I need connections between the nodes to be like this:

[image]

How do I do this in d3?

This is my current code with diagonal.

```html
<html>
<head>
<title> Box office </title>
</head>
<body>
<style>
.node {
  cursor: pointer;
 }

 .node circle {
   fill: #fff;
   stroke: steelblue;
   stroke-width: 3px;
 }

 .node text {
   font: 12px sans-serif;
 }

 .link {
   fill: none;
   stroke: #ccc;
   stroke-width: 2px;
 }

</style>
<!-- load the d3.js library --> 
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

<div id = "boxoffice"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">



var sampleData = [
  {
    "ChangeFlowsFromParent": "false",
    "ChangeFlowsToParent": "false",
    "StreamType": "Mainline",
    "streamName": "ArgOS_2_0",
    "Parent": "none",
    "Compliance": "Released",
    "children": [
      {
        "ChangeFlowsFromParent": "true",
        "ChangeFlowsToParent": "true",
        "StreamType": "Development",
        "streamName": "ArgOS_2_0_DHAL",
        "Parent": "ArgOS_2_0",
        "Compliance": "Released"
      },
    {
        "ChangeFlowsFromParent": "true",
        "ChangeFlowsToParent": "true",
        "StreamType": "Development",
        "streamName": "ArgOS_2_0_Dev",
        "Parent": "ArgOS_2_0",
        "Compliance": "Released",
        "children": [
          {
            "ChangeFlowsFromParent": "true",
            "ChangeFlowsToParent": "true",
            "StreamType": "Release",
            "streamName": "r_ArgOS_0230",
            "Parent": "ArgOS_2_0_Dev",
            "Compliance": "Released"
          },
     {
            "ChangeFlowsFromParent": "true",
            "ChangeFlowsToParent": "true",
            "StreamType": "Release",
            "streamName": "branch1",
            "Parent": "ArgOS_2_0_Dev",
            "Compliance": "Released",
    "children": [
     {
    "ChangeFlowsFromParent": "true",
    "ChangeFlowsToParent": "true",
    "StreamType": "Release",
    "streamName": "branch100",
    "Parent": "branch1",
    "Compliance": "Released"
     },
     {
    "ChangeFlowsFromParent": "true",
    "ChangeFlowsToParent": "true",
    "StreamType": "Release",
    "streamName": "branch200",
    "Parent": "branch1",
    "Compliance": "Released",
     "children": [
      {
     "ChangeFlowsFromParent": "true",
     "ChangeFlowsToParent": "true",
     "StreamType": "Release",
     "streamName": "honey",
     "Parent": "branch200",
     "Compliance": "Released"
      }
      ]
     }
     ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        "ChangeFlowsFromParent": "true",
        "ChangeFlowsToParent": "true",
        "StreamType": "Development",
        "streamName": "ArgOS_2_0_IPC-Tracer",
        "Parent": "ArgOS_2_0",
        "Compliance": "Released",
    "children": [
     {
    "ChangeFlowsFromParent": "true",
    "ChangeFlowsToParent": "true",
    "StreamType": "Release",
    "streamName": "ArgOS_2_0_IPC_child 1",
    "Parent": "ArgOS_2_0_IPC",
    "Compliance": "Released"
     },
     {
    "ChangeFlowsFromParent": "true",
    "ChangeFlowsToParent": "true",
    "StreamType": "Release",
    "streamName": "ArgOS_2_0_IPC_child 2",
    "Parent": "ArgOS_2_0_IPC",
    "Compliance": "Released"
     }
     ]
      },
      {
        "ChangeFlowsFromParent": "true",
        "ChangeFlowsToParent": "true",
        "StreamType": "Development",
        "streamName": "ArgOS_2_0_NSW_Temp",
        "Parent": "ArgOS_2_0",
        "Compliance": "Released"
      },
      {
        "ChangeFlowsFromParent": "true",
        "ChangeFlowsToParent": "true",
        "StreamType": "Development",
        "streamName": "ArgOS_2_0_Test",
        "Parent": "ArgOS_2_0",
        "Compliance": "Released"
      },
      {
        "ChangeFlowsFromParent": "true",
        "ChangeFlowsToParent": "true",
        "StreamType": "Development",
        "streamName": "ArgOS_2_CBD",
        "Parent": "ArgOS_2_0",
        "Compliance": "Released"
      },
      {
        "ChangeFlowsFromParent": "true",
        "ChangeFlowsToParent": "true",
        "StreamType": "Development",
        "streamName": "test_mergewp",
        "Parent": "ArgOS_2_0",
        "Compliance": "Released"
      }
    ]
  }
]


var margin = {top:100, bottom: 100, left:100, right:100},
width = 1800 - margin.left-margin.right, //total width minus side margins
height = 1500 - margin.top - margin.bottom; //total height minus vertical margins

var tree = d3.layout.tree().size([width, height]);

tree.nodeSize([40,100]);

var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
 .projection(function(d) { return [d.x, -d.y]; });

 

var svgContainer = d3.select("#boxoffice").append("svg").attr("width", width).attr("height", height).append("g").attr("transform", "translate(" + (width/2) + "," + (height - 500) + ")");

var root = sampleData[0];
root.x0 = width/2;
root.y0 = 0;

update(root);

d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", "500px");

function update(sourceNode){

var nodes = tree.nodes(sourceNode).reverse(),
 links = tree.links(nodes);

  
nodes.forEach(function(d){d.y = d.depth * 180});
   

var node = svgContainer.selectAll("g.node").attr("class", "node").data(nodes, function(d, i){return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
        .attr("transform", function(d) { 
        
        <!-- if(d.StreamType == "Mainline") -->
        <!-- return "translate(-100,-100)"; -->
        <!-- else -->
        return "translate(" + sourceNode.y0 + "," + sourceNode.x0 + ")"; 
                
        });
  
nodeEnter.append("circle")
  .attr("r", 15)
  .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });
  
  nodeEnter.append("text")
   .attr("x", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? -13 : 13; })
   .attr("dy", ".35em")
   .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; })
   .text(function(d) { return d.streamName; })
   .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);
 
    
  var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
   .duration(100)
   .attr("transform", function(d) { 
   
    if(d.StreamType == "Mainline")
     {
   var lastElement = nodes[0];
   
  return  "translate(" + (lastElement.y + 100) + "," + (lastElement.x -130) + ")"; //adding the root element 
  }
     else
   return "translate(" + d.y + "," + (d.x-(margin.top + margin.bottom)) + ")"; 
            
   });

  nodeUpdate.select("circle")
   .attr("r", 10)
   .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });

  nodeUpdate.select("text")
   .style("fill-opacity", 1);

  var link = svgContainer.selectAll("path.link")
   .data(links, function(d) { return d.target.id; });
 
  link.enter().insert("path", "g")
  .attr("class", "link")
  .attr("d", function(d) {
 var o = {x: sourceNode.x0, y: sourceNode.y0};
 return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
  });

  // Transition links to their new position.
  link.transition()
   .duration(10)
   .attr("d", diagonal);
     
   
nodes.forEach(function(d) {
 d.x0 = d.x;
 d.y0 = d.y;
  });
   

}

function positionLink(d) {
  return "M" + d[0].x + "," + d[0].y
       + "S" + d[1].x + "," + d[1].y
       + " " + d[2].x + "," + d[2].y;
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

As in this code, the links are all messy. I can tidy it up for diagonal path links, but I want my links to be dynamic and flexible. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear what you mean by "flexible". More accurate terminology can be gathered from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths#Bezier_Curves . For example, you may want a cubic Bezier curve.

To implement this, you will need to alter this section of code:

```
.attr("d", function(d) {
var o = {x: sourceNode.x0, y: sourceNode.y0};
return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
```

More information can be found at this example, which seems to implement what you want:
https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339184

It uses:

```
.attr("d", d3.linkHorizontal()
      .x(function(d) { return d.y; })
      .y(function(d) { return d.x; }));
```

The link capabilities are related, but not equivalent to the diagonal capabilities.

Comment: By flexible, I mean that the links need to be lines like in the picture (no diagonal, no projection, no straight lines  - curved lines running everywhere is what I want). And I tried usign d3.linkHorizontal() - I get script error saying d3.linkHorizontal() is not a function. There isn't much help on the internet for this, either.

Comment: linkHorizontal came with a more recent release of d3 v4 (https://github.com/d3/d3/releases/tag/v4.9.0)

Comment: If I reference version4, it says d3 is not defined.